# How to load an XML file into a database using an SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I am using SSIS in Visual Studio 2008. I have many XML files that I need to process and place into an existing DB structure (SQL Server 2005). This is my first attempt at using SSIS and am  a little stuck. I have found the XML Data Flow task, assigned it a test xml file and it's associated XSD, and mapped one node to a Database Table. My question is, how do I associate many xsd nodes with many tables? Surely I don't have to set up an XML source for each table?

Comment: Are all the XML files of the same schema?

Comment: There is an SSIS bug which prevents looping thorugh XML files in ssis 2008 as of now.....but thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is a possible option which demonstrates how to load multiple XML files having same definition into an SQL Server table. The example uses `SQL Server 2008 R2` and `SSIS 2008 R2`. The example shown here loads three XML files into an SQL table using SSIS `Data Flow Task` with the help of `XML Source` component.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create a table named `dbo.Items` using the script given under **SQL Scripts** section.
2. Create an XSD file named `Items.xsd`  in the folder path **C:\temp\xsd** using the content provided under **XSD File** section.
3. Create three XML files namely `Items_1.xml`, `Items_2.xml` and `Items_3.xml` in the folder path **C:\temp\xml** using the content provided under **XML Files** section.
4. On the package, create 3 variables namely `FileExtension`, `FilePath` and `FolderPath` as shown in screenshot #**1**.
5. On the package's Connection Managers, create an OLE DB Connection named `SQLServer` to connect to the SQL Server Instance as shown in screenshot #**2**.
6. On the `Control Flow` tab, place a `Foreach loop container` and a `Data Flow Task` within the Foreach loop container as shown in screenshot #**3**.
7. Configure the `Foreach Loop container` as shown in screenshots #**4** and #**5**.
8. Double-click on the `Data Flow Task` to navigate to the `Data Flow` tab. Place an `XML Source` component and an `OLE DB Destination` as shown in screenshot #**6**.
9. Configure the `XML Source` as shown in screenshot #**7** and #**8**. The XML file path will be retrieved from the variable **FilePath**. This variable will be populated by the `Foreach Loop container`.
10. Configure the `OLE DB Destination` as shown in screenshots #**9** and #**10**.
11. Screenshots #**11** and #**12** show the package execution.
12. Screenshot #**13** shows the table data **before** the package execution. Screenshot #**14** shows the table data **after** the package execution. The data in the table `dbo.Items` now contains the data present in three XML files.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ItemName] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [numeric](18, 2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**XSD File**

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:schema="ItemsXSDSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" targetNamespace="ItemsXSDSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="Items">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Id" type="sqltypes:int" />
                            <xsd:element name="ItemNumber">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="ItemName">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="60" />
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="Price">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:numeric">
                                        <xsd:totalDigits value="18" />
                                        <xsd:fractionDigits value="2" />
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**XML Files**

**Items_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items xmlns="ItemsXSDSchema">  
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <ItemNumber>I2345343</ItemNumber>
        <ItemName>Monitor</ItemName>
        <Price>299.99</Price>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

**Items_2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items xmlns="ItemsXSDSchema">  
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <ItemNumber>J1231231</ItemNumber>
        <ItemName>Mouse</ItemName>
        <Price>29.99</Price>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

**Items_3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items xmlns="ItemsXSDSchema">  
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <ItemNumber>K0456212</ItemNumber>
        <ItemName>Keyboard</ItemName>
        <Price>49.99</Price>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

**Screenshot #13:**

[image: 13]

**Screenshot #14:**

[image: 13]

Comment: pay attention to the sqltypes in xsd.  This made mine sooooo much easier!  Wish I had found this answer earlier!  I was using a schema definition with regular types and had successful status but no rows were being output.  Correcting the xsd fixed that!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add `@[user::FilePath]` to the `[XML Source].[XMLData]` in the data flow task or the package says **no source file found** after package execution.