# How to parse XML files in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Has anyone done pulling data from a XML file using SSIS ? While pulling , i need to apply conditions too based on the XML nodes from the XML file. How is it possible to get nodes from the XML file and applying conditions with the nodes ? Can you provide me an example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an XML file into a database using an SSIS package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152671/how-to-load-an-xml-file-into-a-database-using-an-ssis-package)

Answer (score 2):

For more complex XML sources it may be easier to use XSLT to fetch all nodes/attributes as required.

See [this article](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/04/20/loading-complex-xml-using-ssis/) for info on how that works.