# SSIS Xml Task - two columns to the database

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, ssis

What I have is XML with country-city pairs (Global Weather web service). I want that data to be loaded to the database table (MS SQL Server). I have done it with XPATH with one column (/City), but don't know how to import two columns to the table. How can I set output to be two columns and make Data Flow load these two columns to the database table?

EDIT:

What I have now is Web Service Task, which takes data from
    http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl
web service. Next, there is Data Flow Task with two things: XML Data Source that takes this XML and SQL Server Destination that loads one column of nodes from this XML to database table.

Comment: Maybe you can give some example what you already did?

Comment: can you post some pictures of your SSIS data flow currently for the XML?

Comment: @Macb simply they are connected forward

Comment: go through this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152671/how-to-load-an-xml-file-into-a-database-using-an-ssis-package hope it resolves your issue. and also please show how your package is transforming

Answer (score 0):

I've already did this by using XSLT transformation. I've readed XML, then transformed it by XSLT to CSV format and then put it into the database table.